# SharpZipLib implementation in SL4

Tags: c#, silverlight

Does any one where we can get SharpZipLib implementation in Silverlight 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Silverlight implementation of `SharpZipLib` [here](http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/).  (Note uses GPLv2 Licence).

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend that you use the open source [DotNetZip](http://www.codeplex.com/DotNetZip) library and not SharpZipLib. DotNetZip is licensed under the Ms-PL and also easier to use than SharpZipLib.

Zipping for example is that easy:

```
 using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
 {
     zip.AddEntry("MyFileName.png", null, pngStream);

     // Save to stream from SaveFileDialog
     zip.Save(stream);
 }
```

Comment: Is there a Silverlight version of this library? Or do know you whether the source compiles when targeting Silverlight?

Comment: +1 On DotNetZip being easier I use it a lot serverside, its very slick, especially the Stream handling. (I create a deep zoom compatible set of folders and files into a Zip file, DotNetZips Just-In-Time input streams are brilliant for that).

Comment: Please not that this isn't supported on XP